# Can't set Content-Type of Azure Blob

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am storing the data on Azure and putting *Content-Type* in the headers field while uploading a chunk like so:

```
const headers: any = {
    'Content-Range': contentRange,
    'Content-Type': "image/svg+xml",
};

const responseData: any = await putChunk(url, chunks[currentChunkIndex].blob, headers);
```

Following is the way I am creating blobs and pushing them into a a chunk array:

```
var blob = new Blob([file.slice(start, end)], { type: 'image/svg+xml' });
const chunk = new FileChunk(blob, file.size, start, end, file.name);
chunks.push(chunk);
```

Following is the putChunk() function that simply sends a PUT request:

```
async function putChunk(url: string, data: any, headers: any): Promise<any> {
            const options: any = {
                method: 'PUT',
                headers: headers,
                body: 
            return await fetch(url, options);
        }
```

No matter what the content-type is set to, of blobs and chunks likewise, it always resets to application/octet-stream. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> No matter what the content-type is set to, it always resets to
>   application/octet-stream. What am I missing?

The issue is that you're setting the content type of the chunk and not that of the blob.

In order to set the content type of the blob, you would need to include `x-ms-blob-content-type` header and set the value as `image/svg+xml` in your [`Put Block List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block-list) request and then you will see proper content type of the blob.